# How does a JVM die due to an OOM exception?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I've looked into a lot of places and couldn't find the reason for a JVM to die due to an OOM. I'm not considering the OS killer. To give some context, I have a Java application running and it starts to run out of memory, I know it may survive after the JVM start killing the threads.

However, I've seen it running for more than 30 minutes after the first OOM and it keeps running in this unresponsive state, it may or not recover. But, I've also seen it crashing right after the first OOM after replicating the same steps to trigger the OOM. The system is fine in the memory side, the problem is just with the JVM. So, my questions are:

1. What happens to the JVM during an OOM that it may crash or remain permanently in an unresponsive state?
2. How the JVM kill the threads? Is it random?

Comment: I would suggest to give us more context for your problem, because you should not get any OutOfMemoryExceptions

Comment: Not sure the JVM is "ever" expected to crash (there might be a couple exotic reasons), in any normal circumstances (which I would argue OOM is). What I guess could happen relatively often, is an OOM occuring in a thread, that is never caught by a `catch` block. Uncaght excpetions/errors bubble up the stack trace, killing the thread that emitted them. If that happens to the only / last non daemon thread, then the JVM exists, as it always does. Could that be your case ?

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to know internals you can checkout [JVM Anatomy](https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/) series

Comment: I'm causing the OOM by reducing the maximum heap because I want to know why it crashes and sometime it doesn't crash. GPI got the idea and it might be that but I can't find any documentation about this specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically an `OutOfMemoryError` is "just another throwable", so it *may or may not* kill the thread it is being thrown in, depending on how that Thread handles its exceptions.

For example, if it has a `catch (Error e)` block at the lowest level then it can "withstand" a lot of problems while still running.

So if your `OutOfMemoryError` is only thrown in threads that handle errors like this gracefully then your system can continue working just fine.

But that is also where the 2 unusual property of `OutOfMemoryError` comes into play:

1. It can be thrown basically *anywhere* where memory is allocated and where *exactly* it will be thrown is so unpredictable as to look random. It's *often* thrown in the place that allocates the most memory, but that's by no means always true.
2. Due to the nature of the error condition it represents it's quite possible to run into the exact same error again while trying to handle the exception (for example you might run out of memory while trying to generate a log message about running out of memory). This recursive nature makes reliably handling an `OOME` incredibly hard.

If you want to be *truly* resilient to OOMs in your application, you must ensure that *all threads* either gracefully handle `OutOfMemoryError`s or are restarted correctly when they don't (via a watchdog or something similar). That's often quite difficult to do, especially when using any libraries that create their own threads.

So the **tl;dr** answers to your questions are:

1. "it depends" on what your threads do to handle exceptions
2. Threads will be killed by failing to handle either the initial exception or failing to handle the exception that happens while trying to handle the initial one. Which thread is getting hit is so unpredictable as to look random.